# MySQL Query is giving incorrect result

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have a table `contribution_request`

```
project_id | instrument_id
--------------------------
     1     |       5
     1     |       6
```

I need to retrieve the `project_id` that has `instrument_id=5` **and** `instrument_id=6` In this example it would be 1.

I guess it is simple but I cant figure out how to do it.

I have tried many different things but none of them gives me the correct result.

**Like :**

```
SELECT cr.project_id 
FROM   contribution_request as cr 
WHERE  cr.project_id = 1 
  AND  cr.project_id = 6
```

**Or this**

```
select p.id, cr.instrument_id from contribution_request as cr, project as p 
where p.id = cr.project_id 
  and cr.instrument_id = 1 
  and cr.instrument_id = 6
```

please help!

Comment: SELECT project_id FROM my_table WHERE instrument_id (5,6) GROUP BY project_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Comment: @Strawberry your solution doesn't work.. `FUNCTION instrument_id does not exist``

Comment: Typo: instrument_id IN(5,6)

Comment: @Lorenzo in your question it's only about two instruments. Will you have to solve for unlimited number of unknown instruments as well? Are you looking for a static query with *named* instruments or a dyanmic query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e059/4/0):

```
SELECT cr1.project_id 
FROM contribution_request as cr1
INNER JOIN contribution_request as cr2 ON cr1.project_id = cr2.project_id 
WHERE cr1.instrument_id = 5 AND cr2.instrument_id = 6
```

Comment: It should be cr1.project_id = 5

Comment: **@Martin K**, yes you are right and i corrected it

Comment: I just don't undertand how a project_id can have both values at the same time...maybe this can be fixed with `where cr1.project_id = 5 OR cr2.project_id = 6` ...flies away...

Comment: I insist...instead of `AND`, should be `OR`... am i right?

Comment: **@Robert Rozas**, no you are not right.  Look at my [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e059/2/0) example that shows how it works.

Comment: **@Robert Rozas**, the reason I am using `cr1.instrument_id = 5 AND cr2.instrument_id = 6` is because they refer to two different instances of the `contribution_request` table.  Hence the `cr1` and `cr2`.

Comment: This solution scales just fine from a performance point of view, but with additional variables, it's going to become a mess to read (and write)!

Comment: Yes actually I would need to have more conditions like `instrument_id = 7 AND instrument_id = 8` etc.. I'm using it for a search service. How should I do to make it work with additional conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND. The column instrument_id wont have two values.

If you need to check for more values use IN (5,6,7,8,...)